# iptables ruleset blocking all network activity?

Tags: networking, server, firewall, iptables

I've gone through numerous trial and error to recently discover that my iptables result is the culprit of blocking all LAN and WAN activity. I know this, because if I comment out the last line in my `interfaces` fill - shown below - I can have usual LAN and WAN access. However, if I do not, I can ping my router, any other node or any unresolved domains.

I doubled check to see if it was the iptables ruleset, by performing `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules`. Therefore, this demonstrates the last line in the `interfaces` file is legal, furthermore confirming that my errors aren't a result of the misuse of the `interfaces` file.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1
iface em1 inet static
      address 192.168.0.5
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      network 192.168.0.0
      broadcast 192.168.0.255
      gateway 192.168.0.1
      dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

What is it about my ruleset that is causing such restrictive network access?

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat May  3 01:24:30 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [491:1788008]
:sshguard - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j sshguard
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1019 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8112 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 58846 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 62598 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 137 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 138 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-P INPUT DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat May  3 01:24:30 2014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first guess: You need [connection tracking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Allowing_Established_Sessions).

Without it I believe reply traffic to your requests are filtered, which is probably not what you want.

Try adding the following before your other input rules:

```
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Before I try this, I feel I must understand it. So basically, it will allow all connections that are *established*, instead of strictly adhering to my current ruleset, which can be perceived as quite strict? So what makes a connection *established*?